# Multiple conditions in while loop C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, operators

I have a function that is being called after an input for validation.
It will check for the range of numbers in groupsize. They cannot be smaller than 1 and no greater than 10. I am also validating it for invalid characters such as letters and symbols.

```
int validateGroupSize(int groupsize[], int i)
{

    while((groupsize[i] < 0 || groupsize[i] > 11) || (!(cin >> groupsize[i])))
    {
            cout << string(60, '\n');
            cout << "Please re-enter customer's group size. " << endl << "Input must be a number and must not be smaller than 1 and greater than 10: " << endl;
            cin >> groupsize[i];
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(20, '\n');
    }

    return groupsize[i];
 }


 int main()
 {
     int groupsize[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
     int i;
     char newentry = 'n';

     do
     {
         cout << string(60, '\n');
         cout << endl << endl << "Please enter customer's group size: " << endl;
         groupsize[i] = validateGroupSize(groupsize, i);

         i++;

         cout << "Would you like to enter another questionare? Enter either 'y' or 'n': " << endl;
         cin >> newentry;

     }while((newentry == 'y') || (newentry == 'Y'));

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

So far the program works for invalid characters, as when I input a letter it will prompt me with the error message. Unfortunately when I input a number that is greater than 10 it will simply ignore the condition and continue with the rest of the program. What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is `i` in main ?

Comment: This should have never compiled.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add here int i. i++ is found inside the while loop in int main to count how many times it has looped.

Comment: `i` isn't initialized during the first call of the function. And you're using it to access an array element. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: That's correct. I have just edited the code.

Comment: You call `cin >> groupsize[i]` 2x in your loop.

Comment: I have removed one "cin >> groupsize[i]", but that doesn't fix the issue. If I enter number greater than 10, code ignores the conditions anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your code uses an uninitialized variable `i` to access the array elements of `groupsize`. Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) in your program, making any resulting unwanted behavior well within the rights of the compiler.

The first place where this happens is this line:

```
groupsize[i] = validateGroupSize(groupsize, i);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`i` should be initialized to `0` at construction, so the above line would be valid. Moreover, it would make the subsequent increment of `i` valid as well.

---

Inside your `validateGroupSize()` function your condition was:

```
while ((groupsize[i] < 0 || groupsize[i] > 11) || (!(cin >> groupsize[i]))
```

which is wrong, because you're executing your validation constraints *before* a value had been extracted into the array element. If `groupsize` wasn't given default values prior to this code (all zeros), this code would be yet another candidate for undefined behavior.

To fix this, simply swap the two conditions: make the extraction occur before the actual validation.

And lastly, remove the nested `cin >> groupsize[i]`. If the condition in the parameters returns true, and the loop doesn't break, the extraction will be performed when the loop executes again.

---

As [JohnnyMopp points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314757/multiple-conditions-in-while-loop-c/21315532#21315532), your validating condition should be changed to what he shows.

Comment: Thank you and @JohnnyMopp so much. It works fine now. I am still a newbie when it comes to programming. Very helpful and now I understand what my problem was. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want 1 <= groupsize <= 10, your test should be:
`groupsize[i] < 1 || groupsize[i] > 10`

```
while(!(cin >> groupsize[i]) || groupsize[i] < 1 || groupsize[i] > 10){ 
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(20, '\n');
    cout << "Please re-enter customer's group size. " << endl << "Input must be a number and must not be smaller than 1 and greater than 10: " << endl;
}
```